# Conditional format based on the comparison with the value of other cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'd like to do the conditional format for all cell value of column B with the rules:

- Bold if B < the first number of column A
- Bold if B > the second number of column A

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks,

Anh

Comment: Align is not available via conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390616/conditional-format-based-on-the-comparison-with-the-value-of-other-cell#comment85799621_49390616) by [Sangbok Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6153990/sangbok-lee):

> Align is not available via conditional formatting. – Sangbok Lee mar 21 at 6:01